# Matlab differentiable symbol

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to define a differntiable sym in MatLab so that

```
sym x y t;
eq = y == x;    
diff(eq,'t') = dy/dt == dx/dt
```

With this Code dy/dt and dx/dt are calculated and 0 is returned. How can I tell matlab that y and x are functions of t?

I do not know the explicit functions, so substituting y and x with their explicit functions is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is this-

```
syms x(t) y(t)
```

Define your functions as-

```
x(t)='your function';
y(t)='your function';
```

And then calculate the differential as follows-

```
diff(x) %since x is only a function of t
diff(y) %since y is only a function of t
```